# attach 2 sqlite database and select tables

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

i have problem when i try to select join tables from different sqlite database with attach database command and put the value into datagridview

they get many error e.g: databases cannot open, ExuteNonQuery error, cannot open connection, cannot open databases.

pathinfo2 as my master db and pathinfo1 as my db2

this my code:

```
Sub slc_smscontact()
    Dim fc1 As String = "Data Source=" + pathinfo2.Text + ";Version=3;"
    Dim SQL As String = "ATTACH '" + pathinfo1.Text + "' AS db2"
    Dim com As New SQLiteCommand(SQL)
    Dim connection As SQLiteConnection = New SQLiteConnection(fc1)
    'connection.ConnectionString = fc1
    com.Connection = connection
    connection.Open()
    Dim retval As Integer = 0
    Try
        retval = com.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("An error occurred, your attach databases was not completed.")
    Finally
        com.Dispose()
    End Try

    SQL = "select distinct a.data1 no_telp, b.data1 nama, db2.sms.address, db2.sms.body, db2.sms.date, db2.sms.date_sent, db2.sms.Thread_id from (select raw_contact_id,data1 from data where mimetype_id = 5) as a, (select raw_contact_id,data1 from data where mimetype_id = 7) as b where a.raw_contact_id = b.raw_contact_id INNER JOIN db2.sms ON data.no_telp = db2.sms.address;"
    com = New SQLiteCommand(SQL)
    com.Connection = connection
    'retval = 0
    Try
        Dim ds3 As New DataSet()
        Dim da3 As New SQLiteDataAdapter(com)
        da3.Fill(ds3)
        grid3.DataSource = ds3.Tables(0).DefaultView
        'retval = com.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("An error occurred, your select was not completed.")
    Finally
        'com.Dispose()
        connection.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

there are anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: If this answered the question please click the checkmark so this post gets moved off the Unanswered List.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for opening, attaching and querying a secondary db:

```vb
Dim SQL = "SELECT Id, Name, Fish, Bird FROM db2.Example"
' "attachment" string
Dim sqlAtt = String.Format("ATTACH '{0}' AS {1} ", sqlFile, "db2")

' connect to "main" db
Using dbcon As New SQLiteConnection(LiteConnStr)

    ' create a command just for the attaching
    Using cmdAtt As New SQLiteCommand(sqlAtt, dbcon)

        dbcon.Open()
        ' execute attachment
        cmdAtt.ExecuteNonQuery()

        ' now run a query on db2 from connection to db1
        Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand(SQL, dbcon)

            dtSample = New DataTable
            dtSample.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
            dgv2.DataSource = dtSample
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

One of the things you want to do is to properly reference the db file to attach (and the main db file for that matter), and a TextBox (ie user input) is a bad start.  Something like this:

```vb
sqlFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments),
                                         "SQLite dbs", "secondary.db")
Dim sqlAtt = String.Format("ATTACH '{0}' AS {1} ", sqlFile, "db2")
```

Enclosing the file name(s) in ticks helps prevent it from being incorrectly read when the path contains a space.

If/when you close (or dispose) the connection the attachment is lost, so you might want to create a method to open and attach the other db and return a `DBConnection` object.

Comment: 'path.combine(. . .)' msg = "path combine not a memmber of string" cannot exuted when try to attach db2. error msg = "C:\ my path databases cannot open databases". @Plutonix, there is another solution? thanks before, i'm new using vb;

Comment: `Path` is a member of `System.IO`.  Add `Imports System.IO` to the top of the file.  But it the part about `is not a member of string` sounds like you implemented it incorrectly